# Angular @Input Formatting

Tags: angular

I have in one component the following...

```
...
<file-downloader [link]="result.downloadLink" [tooltip]="Download file from result.teamName"></file-downloader>
...
```

with the `file-downloader` component looking like... (more code but stripped down)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'file-downloader',
  templateUrl: './downloader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./downloader.component.css']
})
export class DownloaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() link: string;
  @Input() tooltip: string;

}
```

Issue is that I need a formmated version that will take an argument: `[tooltip]="Download file from result.teamName"`

so `result.teamName` is coming in as a collection...

```
<li *ngFor="let result of results">
   <file-downloader [link]="result.downloadLink" [tooltip]="Download file from result.teamName"></file-downloader>
   {{result.teamName}}
</li>
```

As it stands I do not know the syntax to pass a string with formatted args into and `@Input` of the tooltip property of the component. It simply shows a syntax error when ever I try this with various positions of quotes.

using Angular2 not Angular1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it:

```
[tooltip]="'Download file from ' + result.teamName"
```